# Xine always starts muted

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control, xine

I'm suffering from the issue that xine is always starting up muted so that I have to manually increase the volume. I tried all options (with *Configuration experience level* set to maximum). The *startup audio volume* is set to 60% and tried with *restore volume level at startup* both enabled and disabled as well as all other settings I could find.

This started already quite a while ago, I think with Ubuntu 8.04 and seems to be caused by Pulseaudio. Removing `~/.pulse` helps and xine starts up non-muted once but further starts are muted again after the directory is recreated. It links to the `/tmp` folder which is a `tmpfs` RAM disk, so it is deleted at every reboot, but this doesn't

This happens on two installations on quite different computers (Acer Aspire 7720G Laptop and Dell Omniplex 745). I'm using the normal xine v0.99.6 and running Ubuntu 10.10 64bit.
I tried googling it several times in the last two years but never found anything relevant.
I thought it might be caused by an old wrongly updated pulseaudio config file, but it also happens with a fresh installation. The home directory is the same, but I deleted all pulseaudio related user config files I could find and this didn't changed anything.

Deleting `~/.xine` doesn't change anything apart of the Xine config window popping up at the first start afterwards. Running `pulseaudio -k` will make xine start officially muted (Volume at 0%) but with normal sound!

Comment: What happens if you try removing `~/.xine` ?

Comment: @wiplash: See my updated question.

Comment: It seems to be much better with 11.04. There xine starts non-muted most the time.

Comment: Ugh, I hate this bug. The only Xine instance I've ever had that doesn't do it is one that is using ALSA pass-through on a SPDIF port with `audio.device.alsa_front_device:default` and `audio.output.speaker_arrangement:Pass Through` in the config.

Comment: @KeesCook: It works for me now with 11.04.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Please do delete the question.

Comment: @nitstorm: Originally I took this as an configuration issue. The comments and answers I got also went into this direction. It works now for some reason. However, I think the question should be closed rather than deleted. Other users might have similar issues, maybe with older versions or different hardware or configurations and having a record of this around is beneficial.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I have voted to close it off :)

Answer (score 1):

I also found that `audio.pulseaudio_device:auto` also works. Perhaps anything explicit works, which would imply there's something wrong with the code that is supposed to set the default when there is no config file entry.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this string in the ~/.xine/config file:

```
#audio.pulseaudio_device:
```

to

```
audio.pulseaudio_device:pulseaudio
```